# Change bgcolor in LibreOffice Calc cells according to cell value

Tags: libreoffice

I've got a set of tables with latency values in milliseconds.  I've been manually setting the background of the cells as follows:

```
 < 150 ms : green
 < 200 ms : yellow
 < 300 ms : amber
>= 300 ms : red
```

Is there a way I can set some kind of formula to automatically paint the cell bgcolor appropriately?  It's time consuming and far too easy to make errors doing it by hand, especially at any scale.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was easier than I thought it would be:

1. Highlight cells.
2. Select *Format → Conditional Formatting*.